# Testing for Continuity

Tags: limits, continuity

Given the function
$ f(n) =
\begin{cases}
\sin (1/x),  & x \neq 0 \\
0, & x=0
\end{cases} $

describe the interval on which the function is continuous.

I know that the function is continuous at all real values except $x=0$, because $y=1/x$ is continuous at all points except for $x=0$, and $\sin (1/x)$ is a composite function.

But what about the bottom half of the function? It states that there exists a point at $(0,0)$, so why wouldn't it be continuous there as well?

Comment: Because  $\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \sin(1/x))$, so $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) \neq f(0)$

Comment: Recall the definition of continuity requires the limit at the point be equal to the value at that point. You need to check if $$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin \frac{1}{x} = 0$$

Comment: @Aniket Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin \frac{1}{x} $ doesn't exist, indeed for

- $x_n=\frac1{2\pi n}\to 0\implies \sin\frac1{x_n}=\sin 2\pi n=0$
- $x_n=\frac2{\pi (4n-3)}\to 0\implies \sin\frac1{x_n}=\sin \frac{\pi (4n-3)}2 =1$

then recall the definition of continuity.